# Proof that monomorphism is injective

Tags: category-theory, monomorphisms

In category theory, a monomorphism is a situation where

> $g: A \rightarrow B \;\;$ , $\;\;h: A \rightarrow B\;\;$ and $\;\;f:B
>  \rightarrow C$
>
> $f \circ g = f \circ h \;\text{ imples in } \; g = h$

I heard recently something about monomorphism to be an injective homomorphism , but it didn't make sense to me and I still couldn't prove it.

How can I prove that monomorphism is an injective homomorphism (at least for monoids)?

Comment: This is often true, but in general it is *not*. It does not even makes sense without a functor from your category into the category of sets.

Comment: A category with a faithful functor to the category of sets is often called a concrete category, so in this context the question makes more sense. If you consider the category of divisible abelian groups, though, the projection $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a mono but not injective.

Comment: i also heard that, in some cases, this sentence don't hold, but in monoids it does, but i still couldnt prove why, it seems useless to me that injective functions are necessary to hold monomorphism

Comment: You might like to have a look at the answers here for some more information: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644035/is-every-monomorphism-an-injection