# Sub-objects in arbitrary categories

Tags: category-theory

I was working with Rings and recalled that to show that a ring $A$ is subring of a ring $B$, all I need is to show that there is an injection $A\to B$ and then use the first Noether isomorphism theorem. Conversely, given $A\subset B$ subring, the inclusion map is (necessarily) an injective ring map. In essence what I am saying is that

Statement: $f:A\to B$ is an injective ring map $\iff$ $A\cong f(A)\subset B$ subring.

Are there generalizations of this statement to arbitrary categories, even those that are not concrete? Is this statement true in every concrete category?

Comment: See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subobject. Subobjects are simply defined as (isomorphism classes of) monos into the main object.

Comment: A morphism $f : B \longrightarrow C$ in a category is monic if for any morphisms $g,h: A \longrightarrow B$, $fg = fh$ implies $g = h$. Subobjects are defined via monic morphisms.

Comment: Note also, from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1644040/620957: "In a concrete category where the forgetful functor preserves pullbacks, the monomorphisms are precisely the injective maps.". This is satisfied in practice for all reasonable concrete categories, in particaular those where the forgetful functor has a left adjoint. So the categorical notion of subobject coincides with the set-theoretic notion in these cases

Comment: Thanks everyone :))